# getting error "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices "

Tags: python, numpy

```py
    class gameEnv:
        def __init__(self, height, width, music, font):
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.score = 0
            self.music = music
            self.font = font
            self.done = False
            self.TheScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
            self.deadCount = 0
            self.Episodes = 20000
            self.RETURN_IMAGES = True
            self.MOVE_PENALTY = 1
            self.bullet_usage_penalty = 200
            self.ENEMY_PENALTY = 300
            self.EnemyDeath = 25
            self.OBSERVATION_SPACE_VALUES = (self.width, self.height, 3)  # 4
            self.ACTION_SPACE_SIZE = 5
            self.PLAYER_N = 1  # player key in dict
            self.ENEMY_N = 3  # enemy key in dict
            # the dict! (colors)
            self.d = {1: RED,
                      2: BLUE,
                      3: BLACK}
            self.episode_step = 0
            self.observation = None
            self.reward = 0
            self.ShowEvery = 2000

        def get_image(self):
            env = np.zeros((game.width, game.height,), dtype=np.unit8)  # starts an rbg of our size
            env[bullet.X_loc][bullet.Y_loc] = self.d[2]  # sets the bullet location tile to green color
            env[enemy.X_loc][enemy.Y_loc] = self.d[3]  # sets the enemy location to red
            env[player.X_loc][player.Y_loc] = self.d[1]  # sets the player tile to blue
            img = Image.fromarray(env, 'RGB')  # reading to rgb. Apparently. Even tho color definitions are bgr. ???
            return img
```

this is the relevant code, the get_image function has the following exception when running it, I can't understand what the exception is about
and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/athar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/space ship.py", line 491, in <module>
    currentState = game.reset()
  File "C:/Users/athar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/space ship.py", line 121, in reset
    self.observation = np.array(self.get_image())
  File "C:/Users/athar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/space ship.py", line 126, in get_image
    env[bullet.X_loc][bullet.Y_loc] = self.d[2]  # sets the bullet location tile to green color
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i cant understand why its coming and how to fix it
please help

Comment: Don't post all of your code, post only the part which has problems and the error. people are not able to help this way

Comment: Plus, the error is telling you everything already. Try printing `bullet.X_loc` and `bullet.Y_loc` as well as their `type` and see if they are valid indices, which they won't be, otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error.